# javascript or jquery pass parameters from child (iframe) to parent (window) iframe is set to sub domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent-child

I'm trying to find out how gray the area is for the "Same Domain Policy". What I want or need to do rather is pass a handful of variable from my iframe element to the parent window with javascript/jquery some how.

Now a little pretense on it. I have a product I am working on collaboratively and part of the product is set off from the rest in a sub domain. Lets say abc.domain.com. Which when needed while on the main product www.domain.com (domain.com) I click a link which opens a layover that contains an iframe to abc.domain.com which for all general purposes this works fine. However. Upon doing whatever actions I need in the iframe layover element I want to send parameters to my main page so I can set them accordingly and then trigger the layover to close.

My problem is either I haven't figured out how to properly pass variables like this from iframe to parent window, or I am being walled off by the "Same Domain Policy". Which is the case I don't know. But.. in either event I know where theres a will theres a way. And someone has to have figured out how to do it in either case. So that said.. can anyone throw me a bone?

Comment: Have you tried using `parent.your_variable` in the iframe to access the variables from the main page? If so, does the console throw any errors?

Comment: can you provide a code example/illustration?

I've successfully called `parent.xxx` from an iframe but both were *exactly* the same domain name.